# SQL to change part of a datetime to a specific time of that day

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, datetime

I have a use case where I want to use the "Wait by Attribute" function in Journey Builder to wait until a specific time of day to send and I need to figure out the SQL to change just the hour and minute portions of the attribute field to be the time of day I want to send while keeping the day, month, year the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using the DATEADD function to add a fractional day to the date.

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, LOAD_DATE), 0.625) AS SEND
```

Comment: DateAdd() also allows you to add hours (hour, hh) minutes (minute, mi) seconds (second,ss,s) and milliseconds (millisecond,ms). This is not to say your fractional day is not a solution, just that there may be a more 'readable' solution through one of these.